# How to call a helper method in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code in my helper:

```
  def app_state(app)
    state = app.operator_apps.map(&:is_production)
    if state.include?(true) and state.include?(false)
      "Sandbox/Production"
    elsif state.include?(true)
      "Production"
    else
      "Sandbox"
    end
  end
```

and in my view I have done this:

```
<%= app.app_state %>
```

I get the following error:

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `app_state' for #):

Please help me out in solving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting will persist unless an `app_state` method is defined somewhere within `app`'s model.

Try calling the helper method like so:

```
<%= app_state(app) %>
```

Now the `app` object is being passed in as the argument of the `app_state` method, instead of the method being called on the object itself.

Hope that helps!